# How can stop Homebrew installing Postgres as root?

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql, rvm, homebrew

I have a Postgres permissions problem, every time i brew install postgres it does so as root user resulting in permissions denial on `initdb`, `createdb` and or anything else i try.

I `sudo chown` the ownership of `/usr/local/var/postgres` and it seems to change and allow me manual entry into the directory from cmd line, which then only consists of a `server.log` file listing the error:

```
postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
```

I then go to `initdb` and it returns:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "jamesbkemp".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_GB.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

initdb: directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" exists but is not empty
If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
the directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" or run initdb
with an argument other than "/usr/local/var/postgres"
```

I then go back to look at `/usr/local/var/postgres`and the owner has changed back to root. I really am at a loss after many hours on this as to what's going on. Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgresql install as non root is a pain if not impossible, because it was not designed this way: it is a multi-user service.

The same thing here: apache2 as non-root - you would have to build the server yourself changing the configuration a lot.

Let me add that for an experienced datacenter operator this is a strange idea, like driving a race car in your appartment.

Comment: Ha ha ha, love the analogy @Str. can you advise of a way to solve the permissions problem loop that i seem to be stuck in though?

Comment: On startup the database process changes to user postgres anyway, I am afraid you are in a dead end.